# Understanding the given mathematical expression?

Tags: matrices, summation, vectors

in my work, I came across the following expression:

$x_j = \sum_{k\in Q_j}F_{k,j}s_k$---(1)

where $s_k$ is $n_k \times 1$ vector, $F_{k,j}$ is $M_j \times$ $n_k$ matrix and $x_j$ is $M_j \times 1$ vector, $Q_j \subseteq K$.

My query is related to dimension of $x_j$. Basically, I had completely understood that when we multiply a matrix and a vector, we get a vector as in (1) and hence dimension of $x_j$ is $M_j \times 1$.

But, I am getting confused with equation (1) due to **presence of summation symbol in it.**

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum does not change the dimension of the vectors, thus the overall vector has still dimension $M_j \times 1$. You are basically selecting a subset of rows of a bigger matrix $F$ and performing matrix-vector multiplications.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. Could you please give a short example about this? It will help in crystal clear understanding of the concept of use of summation in equation (1).

Comment: Thank you sir ...after lot of brain storming I had understood your point thoroughly ....+1 for you....:) :)

Comment: You are welcome! :) Is it everything clear?

Comment: Yes sir everything is clear...Sir, shall I share the small example here ...just for cross checking from you ?

Comment: Sure, you can edit your question and add the small example there for instance.